# Why is the Google map in my React app completely grey?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React application that includes a Google Maps component using the @react-google-maps/api library. While I've followed the setup correctly and there are no apparent errors in the console or network tab, I'm facing an issue where the map displays as a completely grey area instead of showing the expected map tiles and content.

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import env from "react-dotenv";

const googleApiKey = env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY;

const center = {
  lat: 39.3391178,
  lng: -9.3253742,
};

const zoom = 15;

function Map() {
  const onLoad = (map) => {
    console.log("Map loaded:", map);
  };

  const onUnmount = (map) => {
    console.log("Map unmounted:", map);
  };

  return (
    <section className="h-[400px] pb-16 px-2 lg:px-16">
      <div className="container mx-auto h-full">
        <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={googleApiKey}>
          <GoogleMap
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onUnmount={onUnmount}
            mapContainerClassName="w-full h-full"
            mapTypeId="satellite"
            zoom={zoom}
            center={center}
          >
            <Marker position={center} />
          </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

This is the result:
[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl7eQ.png)

Comment: Have you inspected the rendered map element?

Comment: Yes, I cannot find what's wrong. Also, you can check it here https://rita-artur-wedding.vercel.app/ on the bottom section of the page